# Handling classes inherent from abstract class and type parameter

Tags: c#, inheritance, type-conversion, abstract-class, type-parameter

I have a base abstract class and its abstract type parameter as:

```
public abstract class Database<T> where T : DatabaseItem, new() {
  protected List<T> _items = new List<T> ();
  protected virtual void Read (string[] cols)   {
    T item = new T ();
    ...
}

public abstract class DatabaseItem {
  ...
}
```

Then I have number of children classes inherent from it:

```
public class ShopDatabase : Database<ShopItem> {}
public class ShopItem : DatabaseItem {}

public class WeaponDatabase : Database<WeaponItem> {}
public class WeaponItem : DatabaseItem {}

...
```

Now, I want to put a *Dictionary* to keep track of the databases and a method to return them using *DatabaseItem* type, something like this:

```
Dictionary<Type, Database<DatabaseItem>> databases;

public static Database<T> GetDatabase<T> () where T: DatabaseItem {
  return databasebases [typeof (T)];
}
```

Then it gave me **"'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T'"** error because *DatabaseItem* is abstract. I made *DatabaseItem* as non-abstract type, the error is gone but still lot of type conversion errors came out...

Found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056863/class-mapping-error-t-must-be-a-non-abstract-type-with-a-public-parameterless) but I still not understand...

What's the better solution/structure to achieve this?

Comment: Probably to define an interface for your Database class, eg 

Dictionary<Type, IDatabase>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest you can do is to store `Database<T>` descendants as objects:

```
static class DatabaseManager
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, object> databases = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    // ....

    public static Database<T> GetDatabase<T>()
        where T : DatabaseItem, new()
    {
        return (Database<T>)databases[typeof(T)];
    }
}
```

Even if you turn `DatabaseItem` to non-abstract class with parameterless constructor, this won't help either, because `typeof(Database<ShopItem>) != typeof(Database<DatabaseItem>)`.

Note, that generic constraints for `GetDatabase<T>` method must be the same as for `Database<T>` class.

**Upd**.

> is there a way to know what type parameter a class using? e.g. giving
>   ShopDatabase, I want to get ShopItem. I need it when I initialize
>   databases dictionary

Use reflection:

```
var databaseItemType = typeof(ShopDatabase).BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

For cases like this:

```
class FooDatabase : Database<FooItem> {}
class BooDatabase : FooDatabase {}
// etc...
```

you'll need to loop through inheritance tree to find `Database<FooItem>`.

Comment: I think we nearly there, is there a way to know what type parameter a class using?
e.g. giving ShopDatabase, I want to get ShopItem.

I need it when I initialize *databases* dictionary

Answer (score 1):

The bad news is that you can't use your code without kind of cast. Define a non-generic type or inerface for database, then use this code:

```
Dictionary<Type, Database> databases;
public static Database<T> GetDatabase<T>() where T: DatabaseItem, new()
{
    return databasebases[typeof(T)] as Database<T>;
}
```