# 'DbContext' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Novice in ASP.NET MVC here, trying to follow [this tutorial on generic repositories](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/generic-repository-pattern-entity-framework-asp-net-mvc-and-unit-testing-triangle) to the letter.

Bootstrapper (Unity)

```
public class Bootstrapper
    {
        public static IUnityContainer Initialise()
        {
            var container = BuildUnityContainer();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
            return container;
        }
        private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            RegisterTypes(container);
            return container;
        }
        public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            // ERROR OCCURS HERE
            container.RegisterType<IRepository<DbSet>, Repository<DbContext, DbSet>>("DataAccessService"); 

            container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor());
            container.RegisterType<ManageController>(new InjectionConstructor());

        }
    }
```

The stack trace

```
'DbContext' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'C' in the generic type or method 'Repository<C, T>'
```

The repository interface

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable
        where T : class
    { 
        IQueryable<T> All();
        T GetById(int? Id);
        void Insert(T entity);
        void Update(T entity);
        void Delete(T entity);
        void Save();
    }
```

The repository itself

```
public abstract class Repository<C,T> : IRepository<T> 
        where T : class
        where C : DbContext, new()
    {
        private C _context = new C();
        public C Context
        {
            get { return _context; }
            set { _context = value; }
        }


        public Repository(C context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // Irrelevant data methods (...)
    }
```

The error occurs when I try to pass the `DbContext` in particular to `RegisterType()`. Similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056863/class-mapping-error-t-must-be-a-non-abstract-type-with-a-public-parameterless).

Comment: You never implemented a `DbContext` class. The definition of `DbContext` in EF is a sealed abstract iirc.

Comment: Also, the tutorial you linked has a big banner at the top saying that it is out of date, and you should be using http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/clean-better-and-sexier-generic-repository-implementation-for-entity-framework instead.

Comment: Oh sorry didn't notice the banner, where do I implement the DbContext class?