# T must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'TModel' in the generic type or method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, generics, abstract-class

I've tried searching SO for the answer and stumbled upon similar problems but I couldn't manage to use them for solving my problem, so please try not to mark this as a duplicate. Let's move on to the real deal:

I have a generic library for standardizing entity framework database first models.
These are the generic classes that I've created:

```
public abstract class GenericLookupModel : IActive, ICreated, IModified, IIdentity, IStringValue
{
    public bool is_active { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public DateTime created_on { get; set; }
    public string created_by { get; set; }
    public DateTime modified_on { get; set; }
    public string modified_by { get; set; }
    public int id {get;set;}

    public void SetCreated(string creator = "SYSTEM")
    {
        created_by = creator;
        created_on = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public void SetModified(string modifier = "SYSTEM")
    {
        modified_by = modifier;
        modified_on = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

And an class for the ViewModel with pre-set MVC attributes

```
public abstract class GenericLookupViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(300)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(4000)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [DisplayName("Record last modified by")]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Record last modified Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [DisplayName("Record created by")]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Record creation Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

Also, I've created a service class that I intend to use inside the controller for getting the data:

```
public abstract class GenericLookupModelDataService<TModel, TViewModel> : object 
    where TModel : GenericLookupModel, new()
    where TViewModel : GenericLookupViewModel, new()
{
    private readonly DbContext _db;

    private DbContext entities
    {
        get { return _db; }
    }

    public GenericLookupModelDataService()
    {
        _db =
            new DbContext(
                System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TViewModel> ReadAllActive()
    {
        return entities.Set<TModel>().Where(x => x.is_active).Select(product => new TViewModel
        {
            ID = product.id,
            Active = product.is_active,
            Description = product.description,
            Name = product.value,
            CreatedBy = product.created_by,
            CreatedOn = product.created_on,
            ModifiedBy = product.modified_by,
            ModifiedOn = product.modified_on
        });
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TViewModel> Read()
    {
        return entities.Set<TModel>().Select(product => new TViewModel
        {
            ID = product.id,
            Active = product.is_active,
            Description = product.description,
            Name = product.value,
            CreatedBy = product.created_by,
            CreatedOn = product.created_on,
            ModifiedBy = product.modified_by,
            ModifiedOn = product.modified_on
        });
    }

    public virtual void Create(TViewModel product, string username = "SYSTEM")
    {
        var entity = new TModel
        {
            is_active = product.Active,
            description = product.Description,
            value = product.Name,
        };

        entity.SetCreated();
        entity.SetModified();

        _db.Set<TModel>().Add(entity);
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public virtual void Update(TViewModel product, string username = "SYSTEM")
    {
        var entity = new TModel
        {
            id = product.ID,
            is_active = product.Active,
            description = product.Description,
            value = product.Name
        };
        entity.SetModified();


        _db.Set<TModel>().Attach(entity);
        entities.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        entities.SaveChanges();
    }

    public virtual void Destroy(TViewModel product)
    {
        var entity = new TModel {id = product.ID};

        entities.Set<TModel>().Attach(entity);
        entities.Set<TModel>().Remove(entity);
        entities.SaveChanges();
    }

    public virtual TViewModel GetByID(int ID)
    {
        var item = entities.Set<TModel>().Find(ID);
        var result = new TViewModel
        {
            ID = item.id,
            Active = item.is_active,
            CreatedBy = item.created_by,
            CreatedOn = item.created_on,
            Description = item.description,
            ModifiedBy = item.modified_by,
            ModifiedOn = item.modified_on,
            Name = item.value
        };
        return result;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        entities.Dispose();
    }

}
```

The library compiles fine, I use it inside the data layer project inside my MVC App. Start off by creating a new view model:

```
public class RoleViewModel : GenericLookupViewModel
{


}
```

Then, lets create a service:

```
public class RoleService : GenericLookupModelDataService<tblkp_Role, RoleViewModel> 
{

}
```

Make the Entity Framework class inherit from the abstract model:

```
partial class tblkp_Role : GenericLookupModel
{

}
```

Finally let's create our controller:

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    private RoleService roleService;

    public EmployeeController()
    {
        dataService = new EmployeeService();
        PopulateLookups();
    }

    private void PopulateLookups()
    {
        roleService = new RoleService();
        ViewData["roles"] = roleService.ReadAllActive();
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

Sorry for the wall-of-code, some code has already been removed for brevity.
While compiling it gives me 3 errors:
[image]

**UPDATE**: Provided tblk_Role class generated automatically by EF (DB First approach):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class tblkp_Role
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public tblkp_Role()
    {
        this.tbl_Employee = new HashSet<tbl_Employee>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string desciption { get; set; }
    public bool is_active { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime created_on { get; set; }
    public string created_by { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime modified_on { get; set; }
    public string modified_by { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<tbl_Employee> tbl_Employee { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**: Erros in plain text format:

> Error 33  'DataLayer.Model.tblkp_Role' must be a non-abstract type
>   with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as
>   parameter 'TModel' in the generic type or method
>   'MyLib.Model.GenericLookupModelDataService<TModel,TViewModel>'  c:\Projects\Sources\MyLib\bin\Release\MyLib.dll
>
> Error 32  The type 'DataLayer.Model.tblkp_Role' cannot be used as type
>   parameter 'TModel' in the generic type or method
>   'MyLib.Model.GenericLookupModelDataService<TModel,TViewModel>'. There
>   is no boxing conversion from 'DataLayer.Model.tblkp_Role' to
>   'MyLib.Model.GenericLookupModel'. c:\Projects\Sources\MyLib\bin\Release\MyLib.dll

Comment: One of your errors says you need to add a reference. Have you done that?

Comment: To explain that: In your controller you are using the `RoleService`, which directly inherits from `GenericLookupModelDataService<tblkp_Role, RoleViewModel>`. A consequence of this design is that any other class that uses the `RoleService` (for example your `EmployeeController`) must also have direct knowledge of everything directly exposed in the inheritance tree. Thus, also `tblkp_Role` needs to be known by your controller.

Comment: Yes, I did. Library reference exists in all 3 projects in my solution. Seems controller doesn't have any problems knowing tblkp_Role

Comment: You only show a partial definition of `tblkp_Role`. Is it non-abstract? Does it have a public parameterless constructor?

Comment: Yes, it's non-abstract and has a public parameterless contstructor, indeed. It's generated by Entity Framework Database First approach. I've added it into the code.

Comment: Please copy/paste the errors as text rather than post an image (which is not very friendly for those with small screens, or are visually impaired, etc.). Many thanks.

Comment: Updated the post with that cosmetic fix. It's in UPDATE 2

Comment: As for the third error, can you reference the needed assembly first? You may need to reference the actual EF package also.

Comment: Are the partial classes defined in different assemblies?

Comment: @tne - partial classes have to be in the same assembly: "*All partial-type definitions meant to be parts of the same type must be defined in the same assembly and the same module (.exe or .dll file). Partial definitions cannot span multiple modules.*" - from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx).

Comment: @WaiHaLee I know, I was thinking that depending on the references, if only one partial class is visible then it might explain a condition (say if only the EF-generated one was visible it would break the constraint on the service). Now I don't think it'd be these errors though, Jeppe is probably right with his answer -- something is missing from the question or else it's something quite surprising.

Comment: @AdrianK. is it possible to create a class that extends tblkp_Role and use this new class instead?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have the following:

```
public abstract class GenericLookupModelDataService<TModel, TViewModel> : object 
    where TModel : GenericLookupModel, new()
    where TViewModel : GenericLookupViewModel, new()
{
  // ...
```

That class has two generic paramters called `TModel` and `TViewModel`. Each of these has ***constraints*** to it, indicated after the `where` contextual keyword.

For `TModel` the constraints are:

- a base class constraint requiring that the class `GenericLookupModel` must be a base class of what ever type is substituted in for `TModel`, and
- a constructor constraint `new()` requiring that the type used for `TModel` must expose a `public` instance constructor that takes zero arguments.

One of the errors you ask about is:

> Error  33  'DataLayer.Model.tblkp_Role' must be a non-abstract type
>   with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as
>   parameter 'TModel' in the generic type or method
>   'MyLib.Model.GenericLookupModelDataService<TModel,TViewModel>'

This simply means that the type `tblkp_Role` which you try to use for `TModel` does not conform to the constructor constraint. Do you have the 0-parameter constructor?

Another error you ask about is:

> Error  32  The type 'DataLayer.Model.tblkp_Role' cannot be used as
>   type parameter 'TModel' in the generic type or method
>   'MyLib.Model.GenericLookupModelDataService<TModel,TViewModel>'. There
>   is no boxing conversion from 'DataLayer.Model.tblkp_Role' to
>   'MyLib.Model.GenericLookupModel'.

This indicates that the base class constraint is not met. Since the error text talks about "boxing conversion", it appears that the type `tblkp_Role` which the compiler is using, is in fact a value type (`struct` type, or `enum` type). Types like that can never derive from `GenericLookupModel` as the constraint requires.

It must be that the type `tblkp_Role` that the C# compiler uses, is another type than the type you define with `partial class tblkp_Role : GenericLookupModel`. You may have some conflicting names or some duplicate code/names from referenced projects.

In the image version of your compile-time errors we see that the compiler also complains that the type `tblkp_Role` which you use is declared in an assembly which you have no reference to. Try fixing that one first. Maybe the other ones will go away once the compiler can see all details of `tblkp_Role` because it has the reference to the project that defines that type.

Answer (score 3):

The error you mentioned is usually faced when you try to use the same generic type parameter in different classes without defining all the constraints in at least one of them. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056863/class-mapping-error-t-must-be-a-non-abstract-type-with-a-public-parameterless) Jon Skeet's answer for clarity.

But you are using TModel in only one class here i.e. GenericLookupModelDataService, therefore I tried the following:

I wrote all your code in the same code file that means no external library. Something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RoleService roleService = new RoleService();
    }
}

class RoleService : GenericLookupModelDataService<tblkp_Role, RoleViewModel> 
{ }

public abstract class GenericLookupModelDataService<TModel, TViewModel> : object
    where TModel : GenericLookupModel, new()
    where TViewModel : GenericLookupViewModel, new()
{ }

public abstract class GenericLookupViewModel { }

public abstract class GenericLookupModel { }

public class RoleViewModel : GenericLookupViewModel { }

public partial class tblkp_Role : GenericLookupModel 
{
}

public partial class tblkp_Role
{
    public tblkp_Role()
    {

    }
}
```

This compiles successfully. 
Therefore I suspect that compiler is unaware of the full definition of tblkp_Role.

I would suggest re building the library and re-referencing it again (Also check the reference path to ensure you are not mistakenly referencing older version).

I have faced similar issues with partial classes which are automatically created by EF in DB first approach specifically when I tried to define metadata classes.